# "Fuzzy" search of Mediawiki Commons categories

Tags: api, nlp, wikimedia-commons

I am developing an app that lets **smartphone users** upload a picture to [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org). The user must categorize the picture by typing Commons category names. Typing on a smartphone is slow/painful/erratic, and category names are not obvious, so the app should do its best to guess what category the user is trying to find.

**QUESTION:** Is there an API that takes a string, and returns 1~10 Commons category names that fuzzy-match the beginning of the string?

Requirements:

- Response of the server must be very fast (as-you-type)
- Free, as there is no budget for the app
- Scalability should not be a problem for now, less than 5 concurrent users at any one time

For instance, [Category:Power plants in New Zealand‎](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Power_plants_in_New_Zealand) should be found even if the typed string is:

- `Power plants in New Z` (as-you-type)
- `power plants in new zealand` (lowercase)
- `Power plants in New-Zealand` (dash instead of space)
- `Power plant in New Zealand` (singular)
- `Pwer plants in New Zeland` (typo - ideally)
- `New Zeland power plant` (word order - ideally)

Answer (score 2):

First variant: [MediaWiki API for Commons with search query](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bsearch) for pages of type "Category" (srnamespace=**14**), maximum 10 results (srlimit=**10**), and searched string **your_string**:

```
https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srwhat=text&srenablerewrites=1&srnamespace=14&srlimit=10&srsearch=your_string
```

Second variant: [MediaWiki API for Commons with opensearch](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=opensearch) for maximum 10 results (limit=**10**), and searched string **your_string**:

```
https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&limit=10&suggest=1&search=Category:your_string
```

For your example:

- `Power plants in New Z` returns the desired category on 1st place for the second variant
- `power plants in new zealand` returns the desired category on 1st place for both variants
- `Power plants in New-Zealand` returns the desired category on 4th place for the first variant
- `Power plant in New Zealand` returns the desired category on 4th place for the first variant
- `Pwer plants in New Zeland` and `New Zeland power plant` returns suggestion for the first variant

I couldn't find something better, so if you want you can make some combination of these two variants or you can do compromise and will use one of them.